# how to tell if this endpoint is respecting RESTful standard?

Tags: rest

I am working on an design exercise, where I have to diagram a microservices architecture following restful design principles, so one of the microservices is called **ProductsMicroservice**, there is another microservice called **OrdersMicroservice**, so when this orders microservice tries to create an order, I was planning to make an API call to the ProductsMicroservice to check products stock, so this was the endpoint I was planning to expose at ProductsMicroservice:

`GET /v1/products/availability?id=:id&id=:id` 
Maybe another option could be `GET /v1/products/search?id=:id&id=:id`

but I think that would return a lot more information than what I need, because the idea is to get "just" the availability of multiple products that can be in an order (with each product id passed on the request params), this looks good to me but I just want to make sure if it is restful? If not could you please explain why and how could we make a restful endpoint for the need of checking multiple products availability in one call? Thank you

I have been reading from different sources about RESTful, like for example https://www.baeldung.com/rest-versioning

Answer (score 0):

This looks restful, but please use this template or checklist to make it adhere to the REST standard.

**https://<api_version>/<business_context>/?<parameter=value>&<parameter=value>...**

So your endpoint should look like this:
**GET /v1/products/checkStock?productId=&productId=<value...**

- version - versions help to support multiple clients with different requirements simultaneously
- businessContext - should represent the business context or business domain associated with the microservice
- actionNoun - should represent the action being performed on the subject/Entity
- parameters list - There can be multiple query params based on the requirement, can be different parameterNames or same paramerterNames with multiple values
- Result - should have the minimalist data that is required for consumption by the consumer
- data format - Can be XML or JSON or proprietary format, but JSON is the defacto standard
- security - use SSL for securing the APIs
- pagination/filter/sort on the result - if data is huge, pagination/filter helps to reduce the query time on the DB as well as reduces the data load on the consumer; makes the API faster
- documentation - helps consumers understand the endpoint and its details, examples, error codes with error response

Answer (score 0):

*Does not **look** like* ordinary REST Url. I note "*look*" part as only from URL it's impossible to tell if it's REST or not.

Most important is *how* you implement it, not just URL. You can find many different REST API that are completely different. You can always consult [REST RFC](https://standards.rest/)

1. It should be stateless - you always send authentication information.
2. Url should be *categorized*: `products/availability` or `products/availability/:id` (or even better `products/:id/:action`
3. Sending `POST` to `products/:id` would make changes to system state (product should be created). Same with all other CRUD actions into same URL
4. Response should be in stable known structure. E.g. JSON with proper response headers
5. It must throw corresponding error statuses depending on issue. E.g. when ID is not found 404 error must be thrown (Opposite of e.g. `500 Error occurred`